# scrape multiple pages with static url

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I've asked a similar question about navigating multiple pages with static url from https://ethnicelebs.com/all-celeb and thanks for help! But now I'd like to scrape all ethnicity information of every character listed by clicking at each name. I can navigate all pages right now but my code keeps scraping information from the very first page.

I've tried the following:

```py
url = 'https://ethnicelebs.com/all-celeb'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
while True:

    page = requests.post('https://ethnicelebs.com/all-celebs')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    for href in soup.find_all('a', href=True)[18:]:
        print('Found the URL:{}'.format(href['href']))
        request_href = requests.get(href['href'])
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(request_href.content)
        for each in soup2.find_all('strong')[:-1]:
            print(each.text)

    Next_button = (By.XPATH, "//*[@title='Go to next page']")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(Next_button)).click()
    url = driver.current_url
    time.sleep(5)
```

(Thanks to @Sureshmani!)

I expect the code to scrape each page while navigating instead of only the first page. How can I scrape the current page while it keeps navigating? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood your question due to the nested loop in the previous answer. The following code would work:

```py
url = 'https://ethnicelebs.com/all-celeb'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
while True:
    driver.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    for href in soup.find_all('a', href=True)[18:]:
        print('Found the URL:{}'.format(href['href']))
        driver.get(href['href'])
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
        for each in soup2.find_all('strong')[:-1]:
            print(each.text)

    Next_button = (By.XPATH, "//*[@title='Go to next page']")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(Next_button)).click()
    url = driver.current_url
    time.sleep(5)
```

In your code, you only send a request thru the selenium once at the beginning, and then use `requests` later. To navigate and scrape a page at the same time, you should only use selenium like the example above.

Comment: I was aware of the problem and tried to add url=driver.current_url to get the current page but it was still the same. Do you have any idea about how to fix that?

Comment: It should be page = requests.post(url), instead of the current string.

Comment: it still didn't work because of, I suppose, static url

Comment: Please see the modified answer.